# Авторизация openid

Tags: php, openid

```
<?
define('URL','gekeri6r.beget.tech/openid/openauth.php');//адрес по которому доступен данный скрипт
define('APPLICATION_ID','айди');//application_id приложения
if(empty($_GET['status'])){//генерируем ссылку и перенаправяем пользователя
    $context = stream_context_create(
        array('http' =>
            array(
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'content' => http_build_query(
                    array(
                        'nofollow' => 1,
                        'expires_at' => 300,
                        'redirect_uri' => URL,
                        'application_id' => APPLICATION_ID
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );
    $data=json_decode(@file_get_contents('https://api.worldoftanks.ru/wot/auth/login/', false, $context),true);
    if($data['status']=='ok'){
        header ('Location: '.$data['data']['location']);
        exit();
    }else{
        exit('Не удалось получить ссылку для перенаправления.');
    }
}elseif(isset($_GET['status']) && isset($_GET['access_token']) && isset($_GET['nickname']) && isset($_GET['account_id']) && isset($_GET['expires_at'])){//если пользователь попал на страницу с параметрами, которые устанавливает метод auth/login
    if($_GET['status']!="ok"){
        $error_code=500;
        if(preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/u', $_GET['code'])){
            $error_code=$_GET['code'];
        }
        exit("Ошибка авторизации. Код ошибки: $error_code");
    }elseif($_GET[expires_at]<time()){
        exit("Ошибка авторизации. Срок действия access_token истек.");
    }else{
        $context = stream_context_create(
            array('http' =>
                array(
                    'method'  => 'POST',
                    'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'content' => http_build_query(
                        array(
                            'expires_at' => 14*24*60*60,
                            'access_token' => $_GET['access_token'],
                            'application_id' => APPLICATION_ID
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        );
        $data=json_decode(@file_get_contents('https://api.worldoftanks.ru/wot/auth/prolongate/', false, $context),true);//подтверждаем правдивость полученных параметров
        if($data['status']=="ok"){
            $access_token=$data[data][access_token];
            $expires_at=$data[data][expires_at];
            $account_id=$data[data][account_id];



            exit('Это пользователь с id <b>'.$account_id.'</b><br />Токен <b>'.$access_token.'</b>, он подтвержден и действует до <b>'.date("d.m.Y H:i:s",$expires_at).'</b>');
        }else{
            exit('access_token не подтвержден');
        }
    }
}else{
    $error_code=500;
    if(preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/u', $_GET['code'])){
        $error_code=$_GET['code'];
    }
    exit("Произошла ошибка. Код ошибки: $error_code");
}
?>
```

Подскажите люди добрые, что здесь не так ? в какую сторону думать ? второй день голову ломаю , в поисках ..

```
Не удалось получить ссылку для перенаправления.
```

Comment: Во-первых <? замените на <?php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перед выводом сообщения об ошибке посмотрите, что же содержит $data с помощью var_dump или print_r. У меня вот такой ответ:

```
Array
(
    [status] => error
    [error] => Array
        (
            [code] => 407
            [message] => INVALID_IP_ADDRESS
            [field] => application_id
            [value] => мой ip
        )

)
```

Comment: Спасибо , разобрался, ip который указывал сайта, он не действителен